# Integer pairs with more than 3 common divisors

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, factors

`findPairs` produces the Integer pairs so that the numbers from 1 to N and the pair of numbers have a sum less than 50 and have more than 3 common divisors.

Could the complexity of this code be improved?

```
public class foo {
    static void findPairs(int N) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
                if (commDiv(i, j) > 3 && i + j < 50)
                    System.out.println(i + " , " + j);

            }
        }

    }

    static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (a == 0)
            return b;

        return gcd(b % a, a);
    }

    static int commDiv(int a, int b) {
        int n = gcd(a, b);

        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                if (n / i == i)
                    result += 1;
                else
                    result += 2;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Class names like `foo` have a tendency to be marked as off-topic. We review working code from real projects on code review. Also, what does this code do. The title should indicate a very high level of what the code does, and there could possibly be a paragraph of text about what the code does as well.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I suspect, since in this case the class name is completely irrelevant, the name does not matter at all. Often with Java solutions for programming challenges, they're called Solution or some other name that nobody really cares about. Feel free to point it out in review.

Comment: Although, having said that, this question is phrased like it's looking for alternative implementations instead of a review. But that's a phrasing problem.

Comment: Put an explicit statement in the code what it is to accomplish, including what is and isn't a *trivial* common divisor (a=b=30? a=12, b=24 *and* a=24, b=12?) . Take *produce pairs* literally instead of filtering. Don't consider pairs known not to be admissible.

Comment: Sorry @greybeard. Can you explain " Take produce pairs literally instead of filtering" for me? I haven't got it. Thank you.

Comment: Iterate eligible factors, produce their products.

Answer (score 1):

I have some suggestions.

### Methods naming

Both methods `commDiv` & `gcd` names don’t have any patterns. I suggest you rename them to something easier to guests like :

- `findGreatestCommonDivisor`
- `findCommonDivisor`

I suggest that you rename the method `findPairs` to `printPairs`.

### Code conventions

- A class name always starts with an uppercase.
- A parameter always starts with an lowercase. `(Foo#findPairs)`

### Code style

I suggest that you add the braces to the `if` and `else` blocks, since it can cause confusion and break the condition if you forget to put them when you add code to the block.

### Flattening the [arrow code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/)

In the `commDiv` method, you can remove a level of indentation by inverting the first `if` condition.

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= sqrt; i++) {
   if (n % i != 0) {
      continue;
   }
   //[...]
}
```

### Code optimization

#### `commDiv` method

Move the `java.lang.Math#sqrt` of the `for` section, since it will be called before EACH iteration. 
**Before**

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
   //[...]
}
```

**After**

```java
double sqrt = Math.sqrt(n);
for (int i = 1; i <= sqrt; i++) {
   //[...]
}
```

### Refactored code

```java
public class Foo {

    static void findPairs(int n) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                if (findCommonDivisor(i, j) > 3 && i + j < 50) {
                    System.out.println(i + " , " + j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static int findGreatestCommonDivisor(int a, int b) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return b;
        }

        return findGreatestCommonDivisor(b % a, a);
    }

    static int findCommonDivisor(int a, int b) {
        int n = findGreatestCommonDivisor(a, b);

        int result = 0;
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(n);
        for (int i = 1; i <= sqrt; i++) {
            if (n % i != 0) {
                continue;
            }

            if (n / i == i) {
                result += 1;
            } else {
                result += 2;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```